# jQuery DataTables - Serialize is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery [DataTables](http://datatables.net/).

This is my markup:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <form>
         <table>
              <tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' value='1' /></td>
                    <td>Some Data</td>
              </tr>
         </table>
    </form>
</div>
<button>delete</button>
```

I have multiple rows and each has a checkbox. Normally, I would do this to grab all inputs inside the form:

```
var data = $('form input').serialize();
```

But, since I'm using DataTables, it says [here](http://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html) I should use this instead:

```
var oTable = $('table').dataTable();
var data = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
```

Unfortunately, `console.log(data)` here returns `(empty string)`. I've been reading up on documentation but, so far, nothing has helped.

I tried logging `oTable.fnGetNodes()` and it returns the `tr`'s of the table. I'm at a loss here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<td><input type='checkbox' value='1' /></td>
```

You need the `name` attribute for serialize to work here. Otherwise, it doesn't see any valid form elements inside the form.

```
<td><input type='checkbox' value='1' name='check[]' /></td>
```